# ST_buffer display creates big circle

Tags: postgis, buffer

```
$result = pg_query("SELECT ST_Astext(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(  80.7605 7.67833 )'),1))");
```

ST_buffer display creates big circle..

[image]

Comment: how to add radius in meters??

Comment: as it should, well technically results is polygon (area)

Comment: yes result is in polygon but it creats very big circle when i m using 1 meter ..

Comment: The type of buffer will depend on the units of your projection. If your coordinates are in EPSG4326 then the buffer will be in degrees (1 degree  in your example). To buffer in metres you need to project your coordinates into a metrical projection such as EPSG3857 and then bufffer.

Comment: or you can use geography type instead of geometry , see http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Buffer.html .

Comment: how to project my coordinates into a metrical projection such as EPSG3857

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to revise it with the clarifications that are coming out as Comments, please?  Stack Exchange is different from other Q&A sites and discussion forums you may have visited in that it is the Questions & Answer(s) that are all important and Comments are just there to help improve them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data type GEOGRAPHY for a correct result.

`SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( 80.7605 7.67833 )'),1)::geometry as geom;`.